# Getting root pub key form derived public keys

Tags: public-key

Hello I have a lot of derived public keys and derivation path to them how can I get root public key which was used to generate this pub keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. It is impossible to get the parent public key from the child public keys. This is because a hashing algorithm is used in deriving the child keys and hashing algorithms are not reversible.